# Correct CSS for overriding a drop dwn menu item in bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following CSS (which is loaded last in the page)

```
.dropdown-menu-normal:hover,
.dropdown-menu-normal a:hover
{
    background: transparent!important;
    color: #5cac7c;
    text-decoration: underline!important;
    text-align: right;
    float: right;
}

.dropdown-menu-normal,
.dropdown-menu-normal a
{
    color: #5cac7c!important;
    text-align: right;
    float: right;
}
```

This class is applied to a LI element in a standard bootstrap drop down menu.

This styles a drop down menu item like a normal link floated right in the menu.  Now I can not get the selectors correct to use this CSS without the !important flags can anyone help out?

I know I can just run with this but I really hate having to use !important for something which I should be able to replace directly.

jsFiddle of how it should look using !important http://jsfiddle.net/y67qP/

jsFiddle of it without http://jsfiddle.net/y67qP/1/

Comment: We never modify the bootstrap files to make upgrades easier we have a theme css which modifies the core bootstrap style.  I know we take a hit on download but ease of upgrade is preferred.  We will be merging the files at a later date anyway for deployment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specificity in CSS starts out with four integers (0,0,0,0)

`Inline style == first number`

`Id == Second number`

`Attribute selectors and Pseudo-classes, Classes == Third`

`Type selectors == Fourth`

---

You just need to figure out the specificity of the selectors in the `bootstrap.css` file.

Currently the regular state has a specificy of 12 (one class - two elements)

`.dropdown-menu > li > a` == 12

Yours `.dropdown-menu-normal, .dropdown-menu-normal a` == 10 / 11 respectively

For the regular state to work make your selector more specific like:

`ul .dropdown-menu-normal, ul .dropdown-menu-normal a` and that seems to work.

For the hover just follow the same concept and you'll override it.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/y67qP/3/) is an example

Comment: never though of using ul as well in the selector thanks for this

Comment: will do used them all today been busy ;)

Answer (score 1):

To avoid having to use important you should make your selector more specific i.e. move further back up the DOM to get a more accurate precision on that specific element

e.g. instead of `.dropdown-menu` etc you can start with `.dropdown .dropdown-menu` and then move up further if needed.